# Is it grammatically correct to respond "Yes, I won't go."?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

If I were asked the question "You won't go to the party, right?", would it be incorrect to say "Yes, I won't go"? If one had to choose between "yes" and "no, would it be more grammatically correct to answer literally and say "Yes" or to address the concept of not going and say "No"?

Comment: Neither _yes_ nor _no_ is appropriate alone to answer a negative question, and English has no _doch_. The clearest answer is "I'm not going". If you want to accompany this with a _yes_ or a _no_, feel free; but it adds nothing except ambiguity.

Comment: Well, which choice would be grammatically correct:

"Yes, I won't go" or "No, I won't go". If both are grammatically correct, are both logically correct?

Comment: It's not incorrect, though certainly not the clearest statement one could make.  But many highly confusing statements are perfectly "correct", grammar-wise.  (And in the proper context the statement would most probably be correctly understood.)

Comment: (The "logical" choice would be "Correct, I won't go.")

Comment: Any other opinions? Not that I don't like you, but it's an import ant question to me and I want to make sure that I have the correct answer.

Comment: Agree wit Hot Licks,  you could also respond (since they asked you ***right?***) with, "*Right*, I won't go." or "*Right*, I'm not going."

Comment: The most unambiguous, repeating answer to the question, “Is it correct that you are not going?” is indeed, “Yes, I am not going”. Okay, second-most ambiguous. Number one would be, “Yes, that is correct”.

Answer (score 1):

A simple "yes" or "no" answer would be highly ambiguous. Since you're adding "I won't go," though, it's clear what you mean. Between "Yes, I won't go," and "No, I won't go," the latter is more common. (The concept of grammatical correctness doesn't apply well here because it's an unusual case, not something we have a broad, universally accepted rule for. The best you can do is say something that sounds normal and makes your meaning clear.) Here are a few unambiguous answers you could give:

- Right.
- I won't go.
- That's correct; I'm not going.
- Correct.

Answer (score 0):

(This was supposed to be a comment, but it grew too long in the telling.)

This confusion about how to answer negative questions sometimes perplexes not just non-native learners of English, but native speakers as well, particularly those of a particular bent and background.

In *The Jargon File*, Eric Raymond writes:

> Hackish  speech generally features extremely precise diction, careful
>      word  choice,  a  relatively large working vocabulary, and relatively
>      little  use  of contractions or street slang. Dry humor, irony, puns,
>      and a mildly flippant attitude are highly valued — but an underlying
>      seriousness  and  intelligence  are  essential.  One  should use just
>      enough  jargon  to  communicate  precisely  and identify oneself as a
>      member of the culture; overuse of jargon or a breathless, excessively
>      gung-ho attitude is considered tacky and the mark of a loser.
>
> This  speech  style is a variety of the precisionist English normally
>      spoken  by  scientists,  design engineers, and academics in technical
>      fields.  In  contrast  with the methods of jargon construction, it is
>      fairly constant throughout hackerdom.
>
> It  has  been  observed  that  many  hackers are confused by negative
>      questions  —  or, at least, that the people to whom they are talking
>      are often confused by the sense of their answers. The problem is that
>      they have done so much programming that distinguishes between
>
> ```
>   if (going) ...
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>   if (!going) ...
> ```
>
> that  when they parse the question “Aren't you going?” it may seem to
>      be  asking  the  opposite  question  from “Are you going?”, and so to
>      merit an answer in the opposite sense. This confuses English-speaking
>      non-hackers because they were taught to answer as though the negative
>      part  weren‘t  there.  In  some  other  languages (including Russian,
>      Chinese, and Japanese) the hackish interpretation is standard and the
>      problem  wouldn't  arise. Hackers often find themselves wishing for a
>      word like French *si*, German *doch*, or Dutch *jawel* — a word with
>      which  one  could  unambiguously answer “yes” to a negative question.
>      (See also *mu*)

The bottom line is this:

#### You cannot unambiguously answer a negative question in English with ***either*** of just plain “Yes” ore just plain “No”.

Non-programmers sometimes give native questions a response as though the question had been asked in the affirmative not the negative, while programmers sometimes give a response which is the logical negation of what the non-programmers give, which is what leads to misunderstandings between programmers and muggles and why ESR mentioned it.

This is not a matter of grammar, but of logic and vocabulary or lack thereof.

When faced with a negative *yes/no* question like “Aren’t you going?”, we cannot in English do what French does, where positive questions get the *oui/non* pair but positive questions get the *si/non* pair.  I’ll use 0 and 1 to indicate the boolean truth of the response to the boolean question:

> Est-ce qu’on y va?  (*positive question*)
>
> 1: **Oui**, on y va.  (*agreement with question*)
>
> 0: **Non**, on **n**’y va pas.  (*disagreement with question*)

while negative questions get the *si/non* pair:

> Est-ce qu’on **non** y va pas? (*negative question*)
>
> 0: **Si**, on y va. (*disagreement with question*)
>
> 1: **Non**, on **n**’y va pas. (*agreement with question*)

<sub>(And good luck hearing the difference between *“on y”* and *“on n’y”* in connected speech: there is good reason that auxiliary indicators are required for clarity in speech!)</sub>

When the same *non* (meaning “not” in English) might be agreement (answer=1) or disagreement (answer=0), there is obviously a ***serious problem***. French dodges the problem by having *oui* for agreeing with a positive question and *si* for disagreeing with a negative question.  English has no such possibility, and you are advised never to rely on either interpretation.

This has all been well-covered elsewhere:  don’t answer negative questions with *yes* or *no* unless you intend confusion.